# How can you create Shortcuts from an Android Widget?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, shortcut, android-shortcut

I'm trying to add a new widget functionality to my app, which allows you to create pinned shortcuts from a 'shortcut widget.'

Normally shortcuts in Android are created like in the video below. You long-press the application, select a shortcut, and then you can pin the shortcut onto the homescreen. My app currently implements shortcuts like this following Android developer guidelines.

[image]

However, I noticed the Settings app allows you to create many more shortcuts for your app, by allowing shortcuts to be created through the Settings widget like in the video below.

[image]

I would like to give users of my app the ability to create shortcuts for the many features in my app, however, most launchers can only display four shortcuts from long-pressing.

Does anyone know how the to implement a App Widget that allows you to create many shortcuts, like the Settings app has implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it is added from the App widget section, it's not even related to `appwidgetprovider`. ***If you're trying to create an app widget, then you're on the wrong path.***

I've grabbed some code from my existing projects, hope this helps :)

1.add required permission to **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

2.add **intent-filter** `<action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"/>` , so your
**AndroidManifest.xml** should be something like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.SetupWizardActivity"
        android:label="@string/create_shortcut_label">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

with those lines added, **when the user drags the activity from the widget section to home, the desired activity will be opened.**

3.Here's the code used to create a shortcut:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes;
import androidx.core.content.pm.ShortcutInfoCompat;
import androidx.core.content.pm.ShortcutManagerCompat;
import androidx.core.graphics.drawable.IconCompat;

public class ShortcutCreator {

    public static void vCreateShortcutByActivityClass(Context context, String strShortcutID, Class<?> ActivityClass, String strLabelName, @DrawableRes int resourceID){

        if (ShortcutManagerCompat.isRequestPinShortcutSupported(context)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityClass).setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            ShortcutInfoCompat sic =
                    new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(context, strShortcutID).setIntent(intent).setShortLabel(strLabelName).setIcon(IconCompat.createWithResource(context, resourceID)).build();
            ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut(context, sic, null);

        }else{

            Toast.makeText(context, "Device doesn't support creating shortcuts.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

}
```

*Note: ShortcutID is used to determine if there're duplicated shortcuts.*

4.Now you can do the following modification to your desired activity to call the code for creating shortcut(the activity that displays
many options for creating different shortcuts):

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
            final String strIntentAction = getIntent().getAction();
            if (TextUtils.equals(strIntentAction,Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT)) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_shortcut);
                //display selections here and let user choose shortcut
                //...deleted
                vCreateShortcutByActivityClass(this, "ID_0", SetupWizardActivity.class, "App Settings", R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                finish();
                return;
            }
            
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //codes of your activity opened from launcher
            //...deleted
        }
```

or you can also create a new blank activity for creating a "single"
shortcut, without calling `setContentView()`, if you only need to
create one shortcut:

```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            vCreateShortcutByActivityClass(this, "ID_0", MainActivity.class, "App Settings", R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            finish();
        }
```

---

Note : For devices under Android Nougat(7.1), the target activity that the shortcut tries to open must contain at least one **intent-filter** tag(can be any, consider adding `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>` for hidden activities), otherwise the shortcut may display "app is not installed".